# neo4j how to order by an attribute for 1 node and then a attribute from another node

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graph-databases, cql

So I currently have a neo4j cypher query that matches some values and before it returns the data I have it sorted by an attribute called tid

cql snippet (I have added comments that may be wrong, but it is what I think it is doing. So correct me if I am wrong.):

```
// Neo will order by the attribute tid within the node box in ascending order
order by box.tid

// Neo will then collect each nodes values and set it eql to their respective collections
with user, mission, task, collect(box) as box
with user, mission, {task:collect(task), box:box} as task
with user, {mission:collect(mission), tasks:task} as mission

// Neo will return the values
return {user:user, mission:collect(mission)}
```

The question I have is how do I preserve the returned results where it is ordered by box.tid

But also have it ordered again a 2nd time by mission.wid ?

I have tried:

```
order by box.tid

with user, mission, task, collect(box) as box
with user, mission, {task:collect(task), box:box} as task
with user, {mission:collect(mission), tasks:task} as mission
order by mission.wid
return {user:user, mission:collect(mission)}
```

but it just doesn't work, the returned results still does not sort by mission.wid, but it appears to preserve the order from the previous query.

Any clues?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: In your second snippet, I believe the `mission.wid` line is actually `ORDER BY mission.wid`, and I will proceed accordingly.*

The `ORDER BY mission.wid` clause int the following sub-snippet (from your second snippet) makes no sense.

```
WITH user, {mission:collect(mission), tasks:task} AS mission
ORDER BY mission.wid
```

It tries to order the `mission` object by its `wid` property, but that object has no such property (it only has `mission` and `tasks` properties). Therefore, it does not change the order.